# httpcore 4.5.13 jar does not contain bundle-version in MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-axis, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have transitive dependency on httpcore jar (from httpclient-osgi) bundle for my osgi model.
when start the tomcat server, tomcat does ask for bundle-version of httpcore in MANIFEST.MF file. but MANIFEST.MF doesn't contain that.

Tomcat complains,
The bundle \Servers\tomcat\bundles\ROOT\httpcore-4.4.13.jar does not have a Bundle-Name or Bundle-Version header in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF!

How to resolve this?

Comment: What's "it" and "that"? Please clarify. Better: provide a [mcve] and error messages that you observe.

Comment: Tomcat complains,
The bundle \\Servers\tomcat\bundles\ROOT\httpcore-4.4.13.jar does not have a Bundle-Name or Bundle-Version header in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it seems that the stock httpcore is delivered as classic jar, without the meta information required by OSGi.

I'm not sure if it's an issue of the dependency declaration, but as httpcore is listed as "provided", and you'll naturally have to provide it separately to the OSGi container, my recommendation is to provide the httpcore-osgi variant of the required code (and optionally go deeper on transitive dependencies)